# How to create the Web Application only using asp.net server side technology without using client side technology?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have created a web application in asp.net MVC, C#. When users type ID, I call the API to get the details using the ID. Details contain the Mobile Number, on which OTP is sent. After Giving OTP, he is able to download the other Details in the form of a pdf.
**The way I'm doing right now is as follows**:

1. Give ID, then on submit button, using Ajax  I call the Web API to get check whether the details are present, if Yes, on ajax success the respective mobile number gets OTP using sweet alert.
2. After the user types the valid OTP on Ajax success, I call the pdf controller to show the pdf.

**problems:**

1. Data is visible on ajax success. resulting in insecurity of Web application

please tell me, is there any way to do the above without using ajax calls.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, that ID? Is that a user enter logon id, or is that ID the PK or some such from the database? The user can type in their name, or email, or even some kind of "ID" for their logon. Since that is being typed in, then that is user information. But, that web method based on email or whatever? It can verify the user, and pull some PK id from the database, but that information never needs to be sent to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a Server Side Application like asp.net MVC, you can do so much on the server side for every person visiting to your website. You can use MVC forms to submit this email id or mobile number, and trigger the OTP from the server side. Also you can consume the API from your asp.net Application without exposing the data to the browser.

There are enormous number of tutorials to consume a microservice within asp.net MVC application.

Visit https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-web-api-in-asp-net-mvc-part-two/

Once you integrate a web api to your asp.net application, you can drive the way you want to generate OTP or to grant the file to download.

Comment: How will you validate the OTP?

Comment: You can validate the OTP at Server Side. The Client Side page will just post the entered OTP to the server. Validating the OTP can be done on the asp.net application or at the API level.